# Android Data Types

Tags: android, json, android-listview, types

I am new to `Android` and in need of some assistance. I need to find the proper `**data type**` for my app. The idea is that I will pull a `JSON` array from my server that includes keys for id, title, submission time, etc. I eventually need to adapt this data for a ListView. What's the best way to this? I was thinking I could use a List of `JSON objects/array` or something, but I'm not completely sure. Any help is appreciated and I am happy to clarify if necessary!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It completely depends on how you want to use the data.
Ideally, since it's a JSON Array, you may want to use an `ArrayList<String>` or `ArrayList<Object>`.

You can parse the JSON, and add each String/Object as necessary to the array.

Comment: Is it possible to use ArrayList of HashMaps to do this efficiently? It would be nice to be able to call a value by its ArrayList index and HashMap key

Comment: Yes! Although a little messy, you can define it as `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` (or whatever parameters you wish to use for your HashMap). Since a HashMap is an Object, it falls under the example of `ArrayList<Object>` in my answer.

Comment: Okay cool thanks for your help! I have 4-5 values that I need to put into a custom list item layout in my adapter, so I'm looking for the simplest way to go from JSON data to ListView item

Comment: Could you post a sample of how you formatted your JSON data, to choose the best way to store the data and use it in your ListView?

Comment: Unfortunately my server dev hasn't built those files yet...Sorry! But I think this ArrayList of HashMaps should do the trick